# Blocking access to specific tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-administration

We have PowerBI Users that are now asking for access to our database as datareaders.  I have added a new User, provided the Username/Password to them.  However, I would like to block access to two specific tables due to sensitive information.

The entire database just uses dbo as the schema.  How do I block access to specific tables?

Comment: Did you also make this new user a read-only user? (see: [Is there a simple way to add a read-only user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298493/is-there-a-simple-way-to-add-a-read-only-user) )  Because you do not want a Power-BI user who is capable of updating your data.

Answer (score 4):

A simple [deny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) should be all you need to do:

```
deny select on object::dbo.<table> to <user>;
```